# On Android (pixel6) draw in canvas not working

Tags: javascript, android, animation, canvas, vuejs3

On pixel device when i draw another line/point, all data i was drawed It is being hidden or positioned below the background

I have a function called handleDraw, which is defined as follows:

```
    const handleDraw = () => {
        if (step.value === 2) {
            clearInterval(timer.value);
            return;
    }

  const ctx = testRef.value?.getContext('2d');
  if (!testRef.value || !ctx) return;

  const img = new Image();
  img.src = 'https://localhost:8080/img/2.cbe7aa7f.svg';
  img.onload = () => {
    if (step.value === 0) {
      console.log('draw image?');
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    }

    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
    ctx.beginPath();

    ctx.moveTo(0 + 30 * step.value, 0 + 10 * step.value);
    ctx.lineTo(50, 100);
    ctx.stroke();

    step.value += 1;
  };
};

onMouted(() => {
 timer.value = setInterval(() => {
   handleDraw();

   if (step.value === 2) {
    clearInterval(timer.value);
   }
 }, 500);
});
```

The issue you're encountering is that when drawing the second line, the canvas appears empty except for an error at pixel 6. Another device working well, but on pixel6 not working. Please help me